# How do I pass the objectID of a document inside of a MongoDB Collection in a URL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning how to use databases. I am working on making a simple CRUD application that stores contact information, displays said contact information and allows the user to delete contacts. I am trying to pass an objectID as a parameter inside of the URL. This is how I am attempting to do so:

```
<a href="/contacts/list/<%= this._id %>">Delete</a>
```

I am then trying to send this objectID to a separate page.

```
router.get('/contacts/list/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

If anyone can guide me in the right direction it would be much appretiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you get it to code it will be a string, `ObjectId()` is not a supported type of **JSON**, it's from **BSON** which is MongoDB specific. So when you query database, internally drivers would convert **ObjectId()** to string & present it to you. You can pass it wherever you want as like string & when you query/delete a document using that you need to convert `string` from `ObjectId()` to match with type of `_id` field in database.

**mongodb Driver :**

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const id = new ObjectId(objectIdSring);
```

**mongoose :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(objectIdSring);
```

**Note :** You don't need to do that conversion by yourself when using [.findByIdAndDelete()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete) function provided by mongoose - which actually takes in a string & internally it would convert to **ObjectId()**. Not only this it has few other functions similar to this, you can check for functions with syntax : `.findById*****`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I am still getting the same error. The new page says: Cannot GET /contacts/delete/%3C%25=%20this._id%20%25%253E

Comment: The error says it cannot get my URL the message is:                                                         Cannot GET /contacts/delete/%3C%25=%20this._id%20%25%253E

Comment: @VrajPatel : Did you test the url in postman ? Can you give me the url that you're accessing.

Comment: I did not test it on postman. I am trying to get "/contacts/delete/<%= this._id %>" when the user presses the hyperlink.

Comment: Instead of using router to get I tried declaring a const app (const app = express();) and using that but that gave me the same error.

Comment: @VrajPatel : I that end-point `delete` or `get`? It definitely should be a code issue, but in general this answer can explain on how to pass `ObjectId()` values across the code, you can close this question & raise a new question tagged to node.js with all the code to see why your API is failing..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.